# ie6 Showing Image(.PNG) background-color for a transparent background

Tags: html, css, png, transparency, internet-explorer-6

Hi guys I have a problem of images showing background-color on IE6 and its supposed to be a transparent background. on all the other browsers it is showing fine except for IE6.

can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong. tried the opacity to 0 but its still showing the background-color.

Comment: Are people still this clueless about IE6? *-sigh-*

Comment: IE6 SP3 is the last version of IE6 being supported by Microsoft nowadays, and will continue to be until 2014. I personally only support backwards until IE7. But of course, you're here for answers. So I apologize for my off-topicness.

Comment: Convert your PNG to GIF and make alpha value to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is quite simple. No need to include any JavaScript. Define your css like this and include your image name in filter.

```
.whatever {
    background: none; /* Hide the current background image so you can replace it with the filter*/
    width: 500px; /* Must specify width */
    height: 176px; /* Must specify height */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='vehicles.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, appreciated a lot.

Comment: Hey Hussein,I've implemented the fix, but it seems like the height property is increasing the entire DIV and pushes the other elements, i've tried to clear: both, the line height, but it is giving the DIV height instead of an Image height. Can you please let me know if there is something i can do just to set the image height not the DIV?

Comment: You must specify your div height which has the class whatever as i mentioned above. image.png is only a background and will take the height of the div.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doesn't support semi-transparent PNGs. Try something like this for a work-around if you really need to:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/png-hack-for-ie-6/
or http://www.jay-han.com/2008/10/15/unit-png-fix-best-ie-png-hack/

Or just drop IE6, it's way behind all other browsers, and fast losing market.

Comment: i wish i cud but this project aint for my own personal use its for the clients, if was my own i wud leave out IE6.

Comment: @Donald, no worries! yes I'm sure you'd rather leave it out :)

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doesn't support transparent PNGs properly.

[This page](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/pngbehavior/pngbehavior.html) has a fix which involves a behaviour file.  Alternatively you could use GIFs.